# Hide hostapd SSID broadcast once client connected

Tags: pi-3, wifi, access-point, hostapd

I would like to hide SSID broadcast from hostapd. I have successfully hide it by change the value of ignore_broadcast_ssid into 1 then reboot the pi which means the client will be disconnected when rebooting.

My question is, Is there any way to hide the SSID without reboot the pi or restart the hostapd service. So that the client can still connected even the SSID is hidden.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by hiding your SSID? It doesn't improve security, as soon as a client connects a hidden SSID can be seen in WIFi packets. BTW you need `scan_ssid=1` in your supplicant file to connect to a hidden SSID.

Answer (score 2):

A client that knows the SSID will connect even if the SSID is hidden. So there is no need to hide it after the client connects, just run with it hidden all the time.

You can manually add a new client just by entering the SSID into the wpa_supplicant.conf file along with the password. You should also be able to do it with what ever GUI tools are available, but I don't tend to run X/GUI on my pi's.